# Two identical while loop functions, the second doesn't work

Tags: php, while-loop

I've got a problem with my php script. The script generates two `<ul>`'s, one with the images, another with the thumbnails. The php runs through the first while loop perfectly, but my `<ul>` for thumbnails always comes back empty. I've been working through it to no luck, and I can't seem to get the script to print any errors. Help?

```
include "../backend/connect.php";
$query = "select image_id from images where thumb != '';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
<div id="main">
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $img_id = $row['image_id'];
            ?>
            <li class="hidden" id="<?php print($img_id); ?>" style="background-image:url(/pull.php?id=<?php print($img_id);?>&thumb=false)"></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li class="" id="focus"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="side">
    <div id="photos"><ul>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $img_id = $row['image_id'];
    ?>
        <div class="imgDiv" id="<?php print($img_id); ?>" >
            <li>
                <img src="pull.php?id=<?php print($img_id);?>&thumb=true" class="thumbnail"/>

            </li>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're using a while loop to loop through the results, you cant do it twice.

Call `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` to reset the internal pointer back to the first record after your first time through the results to start over.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a performance benefit to resetting the internal pointer and reusing the same resource as opposed to dumping the contents into an array?  (Excepting enormous result sets, naturally.)  Just curious as I've never thought of doing it that way...

Comment: I'm not sure without actual testing but it would seem to me that dumping the results into an additional array would double the memory used, however small the result set it.

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) will only take up the memory required by each individual row, because you're just fetching one row at a time into memory... dumping to an array before looping will use total memory of the sum of all of the rows in the result set... and the performance overhead for resetting the resultset pointer will be minimal... less even than building an array from the resultset

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you read all the rows in the first loop, and there's nothing left to read by the time you get to the second loop :)

Comment: So I need to resend the query?

Comment: Yes. Or store the original results to an array.

Comment: Or, preferably, just reset the result pointer to the beginning.

Comment: I agree with @Wiseguy, it's in my answer.

Comment: I'm used to forward-only cursors on other databases.  Fiddling with cursor position (outside of MoveNext) just isn't a habit I'm willing to get into :)

Comment: With `mysql_query()`, the entire result set is immediately loaded into memory, so it may as well just be an array. Simply duplicating it into an array would basically be redundant. This differs from [`mysql_unbuffered_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_unbuffered_query), which does _not_ load the entire result set automatically. In that case, `mysql_data_seek()` _cannot_ be used in the way @JohnBoker suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `while` loops until `mysql_fetch_array($result)` is false/empty.  You never assign a new value to $result, so when you get to your second `while` it skips the loop.

If you want to iterate through the results twice, dump them into an array and use `foreach` to iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you loop through the results, you are actually clearing the $result object. You could possibly loop through once doing something like:

```
$image_ids = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($img_ids, $row['image_id']);
}
?>
```

and then loop through that array while generating your code.